# error CS0176 with avalonia DispatcherTimer.Run()

Tags: c#, avaloniaui

I am getting

`error CS0176: Member 'DispatcherTimer.Run(Func<bool>, TimeSpan, DispatcherPriority)' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead`

from the following code

```cs
DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
...
timer.Run(() => updateTimer(), new TimeSpan(00, 00, 01), DispatcherPriority.Normal); // Problem
timerRunning = "true";
} else if (timerRunning == "true") {
timer.Stop();
    timerRunning = "false";
}
}
public bool updateTimer()
int minutes = seconds / 
int tempSeconds = seconds % 60;
int hours = minutes / 60;
minutes = minutes % 60;
resetTo = (hours+":"+minutes+":"+tempSeconds);
seconds -= 1;
this.FindControl<TextBox>("MainTextBox").Text = resetTo;
if (seconds <= 0) {
    return false;
}else {
    return true;
}
return true;
}
```

I have tried what I could find on `https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0120` and that only resulted in more errors.